# How can I detect patterns in a csv of numeric values ​with a success failure indicator?

Tags: machine-learning, python, unsupervised-learning, pattern-recognition

Hello everyone I have a need and I would like help to identify the technological approach, I tentatively consider that I need unsupervised ml for the following: I have a data dataset about investment projects which has 20 numerical columns such as: successful (1 or 0), roi (value in X that indicates the return), initial investment, current investment, initial percentage available, etc. I would like to be able to detect specific successful patterns by trying to have the greatest number of successful projects (1) or put another way: try to eliminate the greatest number of failed projects (0) but without using the "successful" column and using the other columns 19 columns to detect the pattern, for example: current investment >= 5 & initial investment >= 1000 & initial investment <= 2000 & initial percentage <= 20. And there could be more than one pattern, but the important thing is that they allow us to narrow down the data to have the greatest number of successful projects that have a better ROI.